# updated_at time not matching during rspec unit testing comparision

Tags: unit-testing, rspec-rails

if current_updated_time.eql?(user_obj.updated_at)

While doing update operation we are are comparing updated_at. Running rspec Time and Timezone is not matching properly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem in testing suites, and luckily, there are common solutions.

You could try trimming microseconds off of the compared timestamps (as its possible your RDBMS vendor and your host application language differ somewhat in the most minute measurements of time).

You could try using the [timecop gem](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop), which helps handle these details. You can essentially freeze the current time, create any time related data or comparison values, and use those values for your expectations.

Lastly, be sure you are comparing the correct timezones and date or time datatypes. You might want to look into the documentation for Ruby's Time and Date classes, and if youre using Rails, the TimeWithZone class. Its very common to experience issues between timezone comparisons, so you want to always use a consistent datatype for these comparisons (i.e., dont compare `Date.today` with `Time.now` or with `1.day.ago` as these may all use different timezones). There are lots of blogposts on this subject, so I encourage you to read about comparing Time values in Ruby.

It can help to open up a Ruby console, and experiment with different methodologies for producing time values, so you get a feel for which expression will default to your current system timezone, which will use GMT, etc. Ultimately, make sure you use one consistent datatype and pattern (i.e., same timezone) for producing time values throughout your testing suite.